# d3 bubble force layout with anchored centre node

Tags: d3.js

I've been trying to implement a d3 bubble force layout (someone else's existing example here: http://jsfiddle.net/andycooper/PcjUR/1/) but with one added requirement...

I want the bubbles to collect around a centre node which will 1) be the largest node, and 2) shouldn't move.  In order to achieve that, I'm hoping to simply create a new svg circle (i.e. avoid adding to the data set in the variable "nodes") that I can then somehow reference in the following method to prevent collisions with it....

```
function collide(alpha) {
...
}
```

Sorry for such an open-ended question, but does anyone know if this is possible? (or hopefully has been attempted somewhere before?)  So far the only d3 bubble force layouts I've seen have shown ALL nodes with movement bound by force.

Really appreciate any advice!

Comment: So you want you bubble layout surrounding a non moving larger circle centred on the SVG which doesnt let the bubble layout overlap it ?

Comment: yip exactly! thanks for any thoughts

Comment: ok well just append a circle and use the collide function from the example you gave and use that new circle with the bubble layout

Comment: Hi AJ_91, inside the collide function we have: var quadtree = d3.geom.quadtree(nodes) which I'm assuming I need to add my standalone svg circle to.  But looking at the API, although it's possible to add to quadtree with .add(), it seems like this defines a single point instead of effectively a new "node" (or simple circle in my case).  Just struggling to visualise how to adapt this collide function without impacting my original dataset

Comment: You wont need to. Just change your collide function so that no nodes touch the area in the middle of the SVG canvas

Comment: Thanks for the hint but I'm still really struggling to adapt the collide function with the existing example and API alone.  Feel like I either need to find a similar attempt or at least a collide function using a quadtree containing some basic comments.  If anyone has any information that could help me understand this function a little more (and therefore how to adapt it), it would be hugely appreciated since I'm pretty stuck right now!  Thanks.